# Will updating or patching Magento break my website?

Tags: upgrade, patches, design

We use Magento for our ecommerce, and have a security patch outstanding.  I can probably implement this myself, but my question is, how likely is it to break our website?

We have had it designed by another company, and if I implement patches, and some functions stop working etc, we will have to pay for designers to sort the problems out.  They've quoted £200 for implementing all outstanding upgrades and patches etc and to test them all - they have said that applying updates will require code changes from their side, which is included

Is it quite unlikely that patches and updates won't have any effect on the website?  Should I do it myself or will it be best to pay to get it all sorted by our designers?

Comment: Yes. After insatll patch or upgrade to newer version you should test everything, you can have some errors. If you are not developer i will advice dont try to apply patch. you can make copy of store and then try there. There are some known issues for all patch you can test it after apply path for exampe after applied `SUPEE-6788`  you need to give permision to all static and custom block otherwise it will noy show on store.

Comment: Most likely stuff will break, also depends on which version you are using and if you have many custom modules

Comment: ya. Its a fair deal. Also do check after patching by yourself before you pay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

£200 is a good deal, even if it's just the recent patch SUPEE-8788 on Magento 1.9.2.

From experience, applying Magento patches and fixing everything that was broken by them can take many hours.

Also it is correct that often custom code has to be changed as well, for example when security issues in templates are fixed and the templates are overridden in your theme.

It is a good sign that they know this and explicitly include required code changes **and testing**.